# Where do I use the find_or_create_by method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using the Rails method, find_or_create_by, does it belong in the model or the controller? I am having a hard time understanding how to actually implement this method.

I want my rails application to accept JSON messages from users. The users will be sending data back to the server so it can be saved in the database. That being said, I would assume the user would have to use the 'POST' or 'PATCH method to store or update the data on my server. When I look at my routes the 'POST' method is used by the create action.

I have read the following Rails documentation but it didn't clarify anything to me. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by

Would I place the find_or_create_by method in my create action like so? Or does it belong somewhere else? It doesn't seem right in the create action...

```
class WifiNetworksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @wifi_network = WifiNetwork.find_or_create_by(bssid: params[:bssid],
                                        ssid: params[:ssid],
                                        channel: params[:channel], etc...)
  end
end
```

Ultimately I want:

1. Users to save new networks via JSON if it doesn't exist
2. Users to update existing networks via JSON if certain attributes have improved (like signal strength)

Thank you for your time!

Final Update - Thanks for the great advice everyone! I had to take a bit of everybody's advice to get it to work! Below is what I ended up doing.. Seems to work well with no errors.

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    if @wifi_network = WifiNetwork.find_by(bssid: wifi_network_params[:bssid])
      # Logic for checking whether to update the record or not
      @wifi_network.update_attributes(wifi_network_params) if @wifi_network.rssi < params[:rssi]
      format.json { render :nothing => true }
    else
      # Must be a new wifi network, create it
      @wifi_network = WifiNetwork.create(wifi_network_params)
      format.json { render :nothing => true }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use just `@wifi_network = WifiNetwork.find_or_create_by(params)`

Comment: @Iceman thanks for the suggestion. If 'bssid' were the unique value would that automatically be selected when using the strong params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use strong params you can do this in your controller:

```
def create
  @wifi_network = WifiNetwork.find_or_create_by(bssid: wifi_network_params[:bssid])
  @wifi_network.update_attributes(wifi_network_params)
end
```

Then when a user makes a curl like:

```
 curl -X POST localhost:3000/wifi_networks -d "wifi_network[bssid]=bssid1&wifi_network[ssid]=ssid1&wifi_network[channel]=channel1"
```

your create action will look up a WifiNetwork by it's bssid and update the ssid and channel attributes, or if it doesn't exist it will create a WifiNetwork with the bssid param and then update the newly created record with the rest of the atts. Be careful because if the wifi_network_params for the other attrs are empty they will update the params to nil.

Comment: Robert, thanks for your help. I am attempting your solution now to see if it will work.

Comment: I am trying your solution but it is only sending the bssid through.. Weird.. Ill keep working on it

Comment: did you permit the other attributes in the strong params hash?

Comment: Yeah that fixed it... Trouble shooting some last things with the create action not responding to the json correctly... I am getting an ActionController::UnknownFormat error... just playing with the format blocks now

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be good to take a step back and really think about the interface of your application. Is there any particular reason why you need to use `find_or_create_by` and do everything in one controller action?

Why not simplify things and adhere to REST by having separate 'create' and 'update' actions on your `WifiNetworksController`:

```
class WifiNetworksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @wifi_network = WifiNetwork.new(wifi_network_params)

    if @wifi_network.save
      # success response
    else
      # failure response
    end
  end

 def update
   # params[:id] won't work here if the client sending the request doesn't know the id of the
   # wifi network, so replace it with the attribute you expect to be able to 
   # uniquely identify a WifiNetwork with.
   if @wifi_network = WifiNetwork.find(params[:id])
     # Logic for deciding whether to update or not
     @wifi_network.update_attributes(wifi_network_params) if @wifi_network.signal_strength < params[:signal_strength]
   else
     # wifi_network not found, respond accordingly
   end
 end

 private

 # strong_parameters for Rails 4
 def wifi_network_params
   params.require(:wifi_network).permit(:ssid, :channel,...)
 end
end
```

You could then have validations on your `WifiNetwork` model to ensure that certain attributes are unique, in order to avoid duplicates.

Or, if you really wanted to, you could combine both `create` and `update` into a single action, but `create` probably isn't the best name semantically.

---

EDIT: After your comment gave some background info, there probably isn't any benefit to using find_or_create_by, since you won't be able to tell if the record returned was 'created' or 'retrieved', which would allow you to avoid redundant update operations on it.

Assuming the `bssid` attribute is always a unique parameter:

```
  def create
    if @wifi_network = WifiNetwork.find(params[:bssid])
      # Logic for checking whether to update the record or not
      @wifi_network.update_attributes(wifi_network_params) if @wifi_network.signal_strength < params[:signal_strength]
    else
      # Must be a new wifi network, create it
      @wifi_network = WifiNetwork.create(wifi_network_params)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am using the find_or_create method because it is going to be used by an automated system. I am not sure if you are familiar with Wardriving but basically it will be a raspberry pi looking for free WiFi and open hotspots. My vision would be it would send a JSON message to the server. The raspberry pi isn't really making any decisions on whether or not the record exists, its just going to be blindly shooting the data to the server.

Comment: Nice, I updated my answer since you gave some more background info to the problem which clarifies things.